# How to protect your DHCPD from dhcp starvaton attack? (option82)

Tags: dhcp

How can I protect my dhcpd application on a Debian system from DHCP starvation attacks? Is there any option in the .conf file?

Comment: Give IP addresses based on MAC.  If you have too many machines to do that, you can hire somebody to solve the problem for you.

Comment: This is a public network. I was just wondering if there was an option within the application itself to protect against this.

Comment: large subnets and short lease times

Comment: Which dhcp server are you using?

Comment: DHCPD is the server application

Comment: @Stephen, yes, but _which_ DHCP server program? ISC:s DHCP server in the [isc-dhcp-server package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/isc-dhcp-server)? [dnsmasq](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dnsmasq)? Some other? Or do you just want an answer for some DHCP server, any one?

Comment: Hi it's  Internet Systems Consortium DHCP distribution version 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The layer 2 network should be protected, means that security measure must be in place:
    dhcp snooping (bind ip:mac in database)
    dynamic arp inspection (work hand in hand with dhcp snooping)
    port security - be strict, one mac address per access port if not trunking

By doing this, you can guarantee, when a device is plug into the network that it is unique

Configure DHCP server to only offer ip address to a known set of MAC address